# Netbeans: Creating custom build target to let sources be packaged to JAR...?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, packaging, netbeans6.8

*I ask the question more specific:*

Using Netbeans, is there a possibility to create an additional **custom build target**, 
which would:

- either package all project sources **along with the binaries into a singe JAR**,
- or package all project sources **without the binaries into an additional JAR**?

*Notes:*

- *It's **not** an option for me to modify the text field "Exclude from JAR file:"
  in the project properties, because it wouldn't provide me with an **additional**
  build target ;)*
- *As you can guess, it's for an open source project ;)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank to [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351296/netbeans-creating-custom-build-target-to-let-sources-be-packaged-to-jar/1351311#1351311) resource hint, I reduces the example to minimum complexity:

Following is done to pack only the sources:

```
<!-- depends="jar" have to stay:
    without it, we haven't the variable ${application.title} -->
<target name="MY-EXPORT-SOURCES" depends="jar">
    <echo>MY TARGET: PACKAGING ${application.title} SOURCES</echo>
    <delete file="dist/${application.title}.SOURCES.zip"/>
    <zip destfile="dist/${application.title}.SOURCES.zip" basedir="src"
        includes="**/*.java"/>
</target>
```

To run in Netbeans, do:
build.xml rightclick -> run targets -> other targets -> MY-EXPORT-SOURCES.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/java_warehouse/single_jar/

Might be the trick, just change the targets names to be more appropriate for your use

Comment: The resource looks useful! I'll check it out.

Comment: it was certainly a useful gem for me creating runnable demos for my blog

Answer (score 2):

Yes Sure,

In Netbeans Project...

Right Click on Project and then select Properties.

In Properties window...

Go -> Build -> Packaging...

Remove -> **/*.java,

in Exclude From war file...

thats it...

Let me know, if it helps you...